# Returning the index of the first NaN and number in every row of a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vector

I have a numpy array, for every row id like to know the position of the first NaN and if there are numbers in the row after that NaN.

Let's say i have this matrix

```
[[nan, nan, 0.0, 1.0, nan],
[0.0, nan, nan, nan, 0.0]]
```

Id like to return two vectors, with a length = to the matrix rows where the first contains the index of the first nan in the row and the second the position of the first number in the row.

```
nan_vector = [0, 1]
num_vector = [2, 0]
```

How do i achieve this?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example and expected output.

Comment: Just did, thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `np.isnan` with `np.argmax` or `np.argmin`:

```
nan_vector = np.isnan(a).argmax(axis=1)
num_vector = np.isnan(a).argmin(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> nan_vector
array([0, 1])

>>> num_vector
array([2, 0])
```